# Inheritance across different (shared) projects & namespaces

Tags: c#, inheritance

My solution contains three projects:

- Shared Project

  - Contains a `LowestLevel` class, and a `MidLevel` class which inherits from `LowestLevel`
- Class Library

  - Contains reference to Shared Project
  - Contains a `HighestLevel` class, which inherits from the `MidLevel` class mentioned above
- Console Application

  - Contains reference to Class Library and Shared Project

[image]

I've included the code for these classes below - note that each project has its own namespace

```
namespace ClassLib
{
    public class HighestLevel : MidLevel
    {
        public HighestLevel() { }
    }
}

namespace SharedProj
{
    public class MidLevel : LowestLevel
    {
        public MidLevel() { }
    }

    public class LowestLevel
    {
        public LowestLevel() { }
    }
}
```

Within my Console Applications `Program` class, I'm trying to create a new instance of the `HighestLevel` class, like so

```
LowestLevel myclass = new HighestLevel();
```

However this giving an error in Visual Studio, stating

`Cannot implicitly convert type ClassLib.HighestLevel to SharedProj.LowestLevel`

Can anyone help me understand why this is, and how I can work around it? It seems that this issue doesnt come up when these three classes are all within the same project/namespace, so perhaps its caused by the approach of splitting these classes across various projects.

Comment: Do you really need to use a shared project? That's not really the recommended way to do things these days.

Comment: In all honesty, probably not. I've never used one before, buy the idea behind this is that the Shared Projects contents will be shared among several different projects. I imagine I could simply convert this to a Class Library and us it in a similar way - do you think that would be more advisable?

Comment: You definitely want Class Library project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the project containing the `LowestLevel` and `MidLevel` code is a *shared project*. This is important because in the shared project model, the sharing is done by reusing the code files, not the actual assemblies. It's essentially the same as copying the code files and using them in both projects. This means the version of `LowestLevel` inside `SharedProj` is a completely different thing to `LowestLevel` inside `ClassLib`.

Shared projects used to be important for things like Xamarin development when you wanted to share codes across platforms but that has now been superseded by creating .NET Standard class libraries instead.

Comment: Nice one, thanks for your help. Not sure why I went for a Shared Project, but it seems like there's absolutely no use for it in a console application.